# At least one option selected from one of two selection groups

Tags: jquery

I have two drop-downs. One for adults and one for children. I am trying to validate the form and need to check if at least one option is selected from either one of the selectors.

**PHP**

```
<select id="adults" class="custom-select attend" required>
    <option value="" selected>0</option>';

for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    echo '
    <option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}

echo '
</select>

<select id="adults" class="custom-select attend" required>
    <option value="" selected>0</option>';

for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
    echo '
    <option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}

echo '
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit-button", function() {
    var atnd = $(".attend");

    if (atnd.val().length == 0) {
         atnd.addClass("is-invalid");
    } else {
        atnd.removeClass("is-invalid");
    }
});

$(document).on("change", ".attend", function() {        
    var ths = $(this);        
    if (ths.val() != "") {
        $(".attend").not(ths).removeAttr("required").removeClass("is-invalid"); 
    }
});
```

It's starting to get too convoluted and I haven't even covered the case where they change original selections back to no options.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 'Id' element should not be same. both drop down have same 'Id= adults' 
check below code

```
  <select id="adults" class="custom-select attend" required>
        <option value="" selected>0</option>';

    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        echo '
        <option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
    }

    echo '
    </select>

    <select id="childrens" class="custom-select attend" required>
        <option value="" selected>0</option>';

    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
        echo '
        <option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
    }

    echo '
    </select>

   var Adults = $("#adults).val();
   var childrens = $("#childrens).val();
   if(Adults  != "" || childrens !="") {
       //Case 1 Selected atleast one value
     }
     else {
      // case 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can check for selected item in this way

```
var selectedAdults = $("#adults option:selected").val();
if(selectedAdults !== "") {
    // You've selected a value
}
else {
    // You haven't selected anything
}
```